# I can't install crunch on fedora 32

Tags: linux, fedora

I installed crunch-3.6 from sourceforge and saved the file and extracted it. Then I opened the terminal as root and navigated to the path of the crunch-3.6 file.I ran `make` on the terminal and I got the following error message:

```
[root@localhost crunch-3.6]# make Building binary... /usr/bin/gcc -pthread -Wall -pedantic -std=c99  -m32 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 crunch.c -lm  -o crunchIn file included from /usr/include/features.h:489,
             from /usr/include/assert.h:35,
             from crunch.c:242:/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:11: fatal error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory
7 | # include <gnu/stubs-32.h>
  |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated.make: *** [Makefile:75: crunch] Error 1
```

kindly help me solve the following error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install a 32bit development environment

```
dnf install glibc-devel-2.31-2.fc32.i686
```